# Copy & Paste not Cut & Paste Python

Tags: windows, python-3.x, shutil

I'm looking for a way to duplicate / clone an excel file from a source directory to a destination directory.  Importantly, the source file(s) must remain in the source directory.  Every example I've been able to find, however, uses the copy function of the shutil module which actually moves the source file to the destination.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is read the contents of the file into a variable, then create a new file where you want and write the contents of your variable in there.

Of course, there are better ways to do it, but this can be made cross-platform and will probably suit all your needs as long as you don't manage big files.

Comment: thank you for the quick response.  I didn't want to parse the file for this operation as error could be introduced from the ETL process.  A standard copy paste type operation would be ideal.